# Splitting on “,” but not “/,”

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, split

**Question**: How do I write an expression to split a string on `','` but not `'/,'`? Later I'll want to replace `'/,'` with `', '`.

Details...

**Delimiter**: `','`

**Skip Char**: `'/'`

**Example input**: `"Mister,Bill,is,made,of/,clay"`

I want to split this input into an array: `{"Mister", "Bill", "is", "made", "of, clay"}`

I know how to do this with a `char prev, cur;` and some indexers, but that seems beta.

Java Regex has a split functionality, but I don't know how to replicate this behavior in C#.

Note: This isn't a duplicate question, this is the same question but for a different language.

Comment: The delimiter and skip char are consts held in a global class. They should be able to change.

Comment: Ultimately, what do you want to do ?

Comment: I'm in the process of creating my own CSV read/writer. We took a look at csvHelper but it provided more functionality than needed. I'm trying to load a CSV file into a List<Dictionary> structure. I'm looking for a straightforward way to go from csv to array.

Comment: @JeffreyHaines: you could also have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) csv-reader or at the builtin [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<!/),");
var result = regex.Split(str);
```

this will split `str` on all commas that are not preceded by a slash. If you want to keep the `'/,'` in the string then this will work for you.

Since you said that you wanted to split the string **and later** replace the `'/,'` with `', '`, you'll want to do the above first *then* you can iterate over the result and replace the strings like so:

```
var replacedResult = result.Select(s => s.Replace("/,", ", ");
```

Comment: Hey, @Luke I can't do the same with python. How to do that? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Luke This helped us a lot. Here is the way that I used to do in python `re.split(r"(?<!\\)\.", path)`. It worked!

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "Mister,Bill,is,made,of/,clay";
var  arr = s.Replace("/,"," ").Split(',');
```

result : `{"Mister", "Bill", "is", "made", "of clay"}`

Comment: Yours is the only one that actually does what was requested, which is much easier than everyone made it out to be. (because he wanted `/,` replaced with a space, as evidenced by his examples)

Comment: But _"Later I'll want to replace '/,' with ','"_. That sounds as if the final array's last item should be: `of,clay`. With your approach the infomation is lost where you have to insert that comma.

Comment: The question was edited so that the example output is now different than it was when he answered.

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex:

```
var result = Regex.Split("Mister,Bill,is,made,of/,clay", "(?<=[^/]),");
```

Comment: a positive lookbehind with a negated character? Seems convoluted.

Comment: @LukeWillis: Indeed, `Regex.Split(",x", "(?<=[^/]),")` returns `{",x"}` but I'd expect `{"", "x"}`.

Comment: @Gabe that's because this requires that each comma be preceded by a character that is not a slash.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Replace to remove the commas from your string :

```
 s.Replace("/,", "//").Split(',').Select(x => x.Replace("//", ","));
```

Comment: that seems optimistic. who's to say the data doesn't already contain "//"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in c#

```
string regex = @"(?:[^\/]),";
var match = Regex.Split("Mister,Bill,is,made,of/,clay", regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

After that you can replace `/,` and continue your operation as you like

Comment: -1, Your code returned `"Miste",
"Bil", 
"i", 
"mad", 
"of/,clay"` 
, which is clearly not correct.

Comment: That's because `(?:<expr>)` is a capturing group. So, any non-slash characters before a comma are being consumed by the `Split`.